# Save and Load different Mac OS Desktop Arrangements

Tags: macos, catalina, desktop

I switch workplaces quite regularly (e.g. from 34" to 24" monitors to solely using my MB Pro) and thus I would like to store and load my desktop arrangements in a simple way. For example, I would like to load arrangement A when I work on a 34" display and load arrangement B on a 24" monitor. With "arrangements" I mean the number of desktops created and the distribution of applications to those individual desktops. Is that possible through Apple software or third-party apps? I run Mac OS 10.15 on a MB Pro 16" 2019.

PS: The suggestion in this post does not help me as it does not allow me to store & load different desktop setups but rather assign applications to monitors: [How can I keep the same desktop arrangement on two different multi-monitor setups?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167396/how-can-i-keep-the-same-desktop-arrangement-on-two-different-multi-monitor-setup)